# Responsive Video Background

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

Im going to use Taylor Swift website [here](https://www.taylorswift.com), that there are two different video background, one for desktop and one for mobile. whats the best way to do this in bootstrap or using a framework like react. Would I still be using:

```
@media (max-width: 768px)
```

In the example there's a portrait video background for mobile & landscape for Desktop.

Any help in making it responive would be appricated

I experimented with bootstrap containers on the background but no success as the video would scale to the device and be zoomed also using the @media its glitchy and the video also zooms in, I don't have the my code atm but if someone can give me a sample or what method is best to use

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Answer (score -1):

You can use video in body and write autoplay muted in it